# Twig accessing array key where is space (PHP allow space on the array key)

Tags: php, symfony, twig

PHP allow in array to be a space in the key like this:

(dump from symfony2)

```
array:9 [▼
"Guest" => 1
"Vip Client" => 2
"Super admin" => 3
]
```

So how can I access the data by key in Twig?
Normaly for the Guest it will be 
    {%  array_name.Guest %}
this will not work
    {% array_name['Vip Client']  %}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use attribute function

```
{{ attribute(array_name, 'Vip Client') }}
```

As suggested here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables

Comment: Thank you It's was very helpfull

Answer (score 8):

You can access like this: `{{ array_name['Guest'] }}` if you want to print. If you want to use it if condition you can write

```
{% if array_name['Vip Client'] == 1 %} {{'Vip Client'}} {% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you It's was very helpfull